# wcf HMAC always fails

Tags: wcf, hmac

I'm trying to implement a HMAC authorization solution with my SOAP WCF service. I already have a message inspector for the client and the server. The server seems to add a "Action" header to the message that is not in the request (verified by fiddler). I then just do

message.WriteBodyContents(xdw);

Which gets around that but then some of the xml elements are self closed (/>) or some are closed like "".

Any suggestions?

EDIT.
I also want the solution to be easy, so far this is all done with an attribute on the service and a one line statement for the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.XmlDsigC14NTransform class in .Net normalizes the XML so that two XMLs with different syntax but similar data are normalized and can be compared byte for byte for a hash.